# Не избыточно ли сочетание слов в предложении "...и при этом еще и"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*"...делает X и при этом еще и [делает] Y",* - будет ли такое построение предложения верным? Не является ли комбинация "и", "при этом", "еще и" избыточной?

Answer (score 4):

Нужно бы посмотреть реальное предложение, вызвавшее сомнение, а предложенная схема возможна: Марина несётся на лыжах с горы и при этом ещё и поёт.

Здесь не два союза И: первый - союз, а вторая (ещё и) - усилительная частица.

Answer (score 0):

Да, комбинация несколько "тяжеловесна" для восприятия и произношения, но вполне употребительна и используема:

Врач должен уметь все  **и при этом еще и** улыбаться.
 Мёд - что может быть сладким  **и при этом еще и** полезным?
  Специалисты придумали способ, как много есть  **и при этом еще и** терять лишний вес.